# Cant get merge conflict to appear locally but Azure devops says I have a conflict?

Tags: merge-conflict-resolution

Normally when I have a merge conflict my visual studio code editor will let me know of the incoming changes, but in this case when I pushed up some code Azure devops said I had a conflict but I cant see where locally.

My local branch wont mention any merge conflicts so Im not really sure how to solve.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be great, unfortunately I cannot add the conflicts tab as some of the other commenters on other posts have suggested so it will have to be done another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following locally on your machine:

- check out your `main` brach (the branch you want to merge into)
- execute `git pull`
- merge your `main` branch into your `maintenance` branch

Now you should see your merge conflict. Resolve the conflict on your `maintenance` branch and push.

Comment: I forgot about this question and figured it out on my own but for future readers this is the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

install this extension to your Azure DevOps it will enable you to resolve the conflict in the pull request

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab